# How to remove the background noise when I connect AUX cable between my acer laptop and my mobile phone?

Tags: laptop, audio, microphone

I am connecting an AUX cable between my Acer laptop and my mobile phone to receive voice from mobile phone via voice call to record it in matlab. when I configured like above mentioned, I am choosing port as mic-in in the dialogue box that pop-up whenever I connect any headphone/aux cable. now when I record it in matlab I am getting background noise/outer sounds from outside that is captured through the microphone of laptop. what should I do to remove this background noise/outer sounds?

Comment: This is normal. Best practice would be to record in an area that has no other sounds. Studios have special sound proof recording booths. If that is not possible, consider purchasing a mobile microphone with SDCard storage, go to a location that has no sound, and record there. You can try to use post effects to filter out the noise, but it will degrade audio quality too.

Comment: Can't I cut off the external sound using any audio settings in laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Send it to [Adobe Speech Enhance](https://podcast.adobe.com/enhance) - free, but requires sign-up. It accepts wav or mp3.

If that can't do it, nothing can. [I'm a professional sound engineer of 40 years' experience & nothing I own can do better.]

Comment: Can't I cut off the external sound using any audio settings in laptop?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know what your setup is or how you have it routed.

Comment: I mentioned above the setup I am dealing with

Comment: Sorry, far too vague to even guess. Also, you asked how to remove it, not how to eliminate at source… for which the answer would start "Use a quieter environment, or a more directional mic or array…"

Comment: Sorry, I should have used eliminate instead of remove.. thanks for your suggestions all the way.